# Specify compression type in Confluent Python Avro Producer

Tags: python, compression, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

Is there a way to specify the `compression.type` in producer configs while using the AvroProducer in Confluent's Kafka (python)?

I tried the following:

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer

from myconfigs import BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL, KEY_SCHEMA, VALUE_SCHEMA

avroProducer = AvroProducer({'bootstrap.servers': BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, 'schema.registry.url': SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL, 'compression.type': 'gzip'},
                            default_key_schema=KEY_SCHEMA, default_value_schema=VALUE_SCHEMA)
```

Got the following error when running this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "confluent_click.py", line 47, in <module>
default_key_schema=KEY_SCHEMA, default_value_schema=VALUE_SCHEMA)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/__init__.py", line 38, in __init__
    super(AvroProducer, self).__init__(config)
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str="No such configuration property: "compression.type""}
```

Also tried specifying `compression_type = 'gzip'` as a param to `AvroProducer()` as

```
avroProducer = AvroProducer({'bootstrap.servers': BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, 'schema.registry.url': SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL},
                            default_key_schema=KEY_SCHEMA, default_value_schema=VALUE_SCHEMA, compression_type='gzip')
```

I didn't expect this to succeed and it didn't.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "confluent_click.py", line 47, in <module>
    default_key_schema=KEY_SCHEMA, default_value_schema=VALUE_SCHEMA, compression_type='gzip')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'compression_type'
```

How can I specify `compression.type` in the producer? I have not been able to find `AvroProducer`'s documentation.

Answer (score 1):

confluent-kafka-python's configuration property for setting the compression type is called `compression.codec` for historical reasons (librdkafka, which predates the current Java client, based its initial configuration properties on the original Scala client which used `compression.codec`).

```
avroProducer = AvroProducer({'bootstrap.servers': BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, 'schema.registry.url': SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL, 'compression.codec': 'gzip'},
                            default_key_schema=KEY_SCHEMA, default_value_schema=VALUE_SCHEMA)
```

Note: the v0.11.4 release of confluent-kafka-python adds a `compression.type` alias.

Full list of configuration settings here: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md